# How to have List Iterator start at a given index?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list and I need to make method that returns an iterator at a given point in the list. I currently have an iterator that starts at the head:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator( )
{
    return new ListIterator();
}
```

All I have for the other one is:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int x )
{
    return new ListIterator();
}
```

I'm not sure how to go about utilizing the given position(x) that won't affect my ListIterator constructor which starts at head.

I tried using a for loop to get to "x" but realized that wouldn't tell the iterator to start there, so I'm quite stumped.

Edit:

```
public ListIterator()
        {
            current = head; // head in the enclosing list
        }
```

Answer (score 10):

Without seeing your implementation, the trivial way to do this is:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int x) {
    if (x < 0 || this.size() < x) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Iterator<E> it = new ListIterator();

    for (; x > 0; --x) {
        it.next(); // ignore the first x values
    }
    return it;
}
```

Otherwise, you could traverse the list to the xth node, but there's no reason you can't do it this way.

Comment: This is not ideal, from the API: `ListIterator<E> listIterator(int index)
Returns a list iterator over the elements in this list (in proper sequence), starting at the specified position in the list.` - Edit: I'm if you have taken offense, I was still typing.

Comment: Yes but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I have to write it for a class otherwise I'd use the one that's already there.

Comment: BTW isn't this code faulty? `--x` will decrease `x` before evaluating the line. So if `x == 1` the loop won't be executed resulting in an iterator that starts at position 0...

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. This way did work, and is probably the easiest way for me to do it without a new constructor, otherwise ListIterator(x) would have worked.

Comment: No it's ok, I was being sloppy (which is why I re-evaluated my vote)! Maybe just add an extra check to see if there is a next element to be safe? Or is that also not required?

Comment: Ya I'm gonna throw in all the exception checks, just wanted to get the base down. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use the `listIterator(index);` method from `List`, in which `index` is an `int` resembling the starting index. Edit: in your case it would be

```
List<...> list = ...;
return list.listIterator(x);
```

Comment: I tried that before, but my ListIterator Constructor doesn't take in anything so that gives me an error. I'll add that in the original text. So for the sake of the assignment I can't add a new constructor, just the method.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up going with this.

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int x){

    Iterator<E> it = new ListIterator();

    for (; x > 0; --x){
        it.next(); 
    }
    return it;
}
```

Given more range I might have added a constructor but without being able to change much this worked the best.

Comment: Good that you included a solution but don't forget to accept and vote on Radiodef's answer!

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer; you've copied the code from one solution here.  I'm really glad to see that it worked for you, but the appropriate action in this case would be to accept and/or upvote the answer that worked out for you best.