# Java List Iterator for Binary File - Question

Tags: java, debugging, iterator

Is it possible to iterate through a binary file given a certain position specified by the user? I've been trying to think of a way to do this but I'm not finding any leads. Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
    String filename = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        System.out.println("Size: " + file.length() + " bytes.");
        System.out.println("Attempting to record file to AList");
        AList<Byte> fileList = new AList<>(); 
        raf.seek(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < raf.length(); i++) {
            fileList.add(raf.readByte());
        }
        System.out.print("Enter byte positon to navigate to: ");
        long pos = in.nextLong();
        in.nextLine();
        ListIterator<Byte> itr = fileList.listIterator(0);
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < file.length()){
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 5 && itr.hasNext() == true){
            raf.seek(pos);
            byte b = raf.readByte();
            System.out.print(((b >= 0 && b <= 15)?"0":"") + Integer.toHexString((int)b & 0x00FF) + " ");
            i++;
        }
```

I'm not even entirely sure if what I've wrote is logically correct. What I'm trying to do is have the user specify a position in the binary file, then I check to see if thats within the files range. Then, it should be able to output the next 5 bytes from that position using an iterator. I'm not entirely sure about the iterator though.

Comment: Is `AList` a class you wrote?

Comment: Yes, AList is a class that I wrote.

Comment: I assume it implements `java.util.List` interface and according to the code you posted, each element in the list is a single byte from the file. So why not just work with the list using the methods of interface `List`?

Comment: How exactly would I go about that? I'm not entirely sure how to construct the loop using the methods that are implemented.

Comment: Have you seen this SO question: [How to have List Iterator start at a given index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146484/how-to-have-list-iterator-start-at-a-given-index)

Comment: So in my original code, how would I get my loop to ignore the bits before the specified position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207699/discussion-between-abra-and-asavyy).

Answer (score 0):

You could just modify the loop reading the file to a) ignore the bytes up to the requested start position, b) read and print the next 5 bytes read, then c) exit.

Comment: I definitely could, however I have to make modifications to the file later on and also I have to print the 5 bytes before the users indicated starting position also. I have to do it using an iterator too, specifically. Is there anyway I could do that?

Comment: You should cite *all* of the constraints in your question.  Handling the 5 bytes before the "start" is easy (just ignore the first start-5 bytes).  An Iterator is not needed; any use of one is making busy-work (for example, put the bytes you *would* print into a list, and then iterate over that to print them).