# Apache POI - How do I start my cellIterator at a specific cell?

Tags: java, iterator, apache-poi

I guess answering the question, how to start an Iterator from a specific index, would help me in figuring out how to begin my cellIterator from a specific cell? I've dropped my code block below:

```
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadSheet.iterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                //Cell cell = row.getCell(7);
                cell = cellIterator.next();
```

How do I get my iterator to start at column (cell) 7?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Simplest thing to do is execute `rowIterator.next()` 6 times before the while loop. Or read more here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146484/how-to-have-list-iterator-start-at-a-given-index

Comment: See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList has a method listIterator(int) which starts from a particular index. I doubt whether rowIterator or columnIteratr provides this. But you can use something like:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
    Iterator<E> iterator = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < index && iterator.hasNext(); i++) {
        iterator.next();
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

Comment: Every `List` has that [method `listIterator(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29)